# How to enable Sleep/Hibernate on a Hyper-V guest VM?

Tags: sleep, hyper-v, hibernate

How do I enable Sleep/Hibernate on a Hyper-V guest VM?

Notes:

- I know I can pause/save the VM from Hyper-V. However, I want to simulate how sleep/hibernate would work on a physical machine - special notifications etc.
- I know to enable hibernation by running `powercfg -h on`, but that fails with `The system firmware does not support hibernation.`
- My Hyper-V is running on Windows 10 1903, as are my guest VMs.

**Background:** I'm developing Windows software that has special handling when a machine goes to sleep/hibernate. The software is intended for physical machines (laptops etc.), but for convenience I want to test it on Hyper-V VMs.

Answer (score 3):

1. Disable dynamic memory on the VM - it's incompatible with hibernation
2. Run the following PowerShell script on the host:

```
Param (
    [string]$VmName,
    [bool]$Enable = $true
)

# To modify, machine must be off
$Vm = Get-VM -Name $VmName
$Vm | Stop-VM -Force -WarningAction Ignore

$wmiComputerSystem = gwmi -namespace root\virtualization\v2 -query "select * from Msvm_ComputerSystem where ElementName= '$VmName'"
$wmi_vsSettingData = $wmiComputerSystem.GetRelated("Msvm_VirtualSystemSettingData","Msvm_SettingsDefineState",$null,$null, "SettingData", "ManagedElement", $false, $null)
 
Write-Output ("Before: EnableHibernation = " + $wmi_vsSettingData.EnableHibernation)

# $wmi_vsSettingData.EnableHibernation = $Enable  # Doesn't work - says The property 'EnableHibernation' cannot be found on this object
# So, need to munge XML ourselves
[xml]$vsSettingsDataXml = $wmi_vsSettingData.gettext(1)
$EnableHibernationNodes = $vsSettingsDataXml.SelectNodes("/INSTANCE/PROPERTY[@NAME='EnableHibernation']")
$EnableHibernationNodes[0].VALUE=$Enable.ToString()

$wmi_vsSettingDataMgmt = Get-WmiObject -Namespace "root\virtualization\v2" -Class Msvm_VirtualSystemManagementService
$job = $wmi_vsSettingDataMgmt.ModifySystemSettings($vsSettingsDataXml.OuterXml)
```

Notes:

- Tested on Windows 10 1903, both host and guest
- Once you run this, you can do the following in the VM:

  - `powercfg -a` shows that Hibernate is available on the system
  - `powercfg -h on` works
  - Power Settings => Additional power settings => Choose what to power button does => Now you can check "Hibernate - Show in Power menu", and you'll get hibernate in the Start=>Power menu.
  - `Shutdown /h` will hibernate
- After you hibernate and restart the machine, you won't be able to connect to it using "Enhanced Session". This is resolved after a full restart of the VM.

Comment: is there anything besides dynamic memory which could prevent hibernate option on the Guest VM? I keep getting the message "Hibernate The system firmware does not support hibernation." olthough the host does.

Comment: You need to run the powershell on the host. I've edited the answer to make this clearer (I hope).

Comment: Thanks, now it makes more sense. Do you have any magic script for enabling S1 and S3 power states?

Comment: Worked great for me; lots of WHQL tests require hibernate/suspend to be enabled, so this makes it possible to use VMs for those (software testing, not hardware).

Comment: @AndreiM: Sorry, I don't see any sleep settings in there. Maybe Hyper-V doesn't support that at all - [This](https://www.tenforums.com/virtualization/178766-no-sleep-options-hyper-v-post2214955.html#post2214955) seems to indicate that.

Comment: Thanks! Worked for me in Windows PowerShell. In the new PoweShell (Core or whatever) it gives "The term 'gwmi' is not recognized as a name of a cmdlet".

Comment: Hmm... odd. Doesn't work for me on Win 10 host (19044.1766). Running the script multiple times simply shows "Before: EnableHibernation = False" each time. No changes on 'powercfg' on the guest OS (also Win 10). Any thoughts?

Comment: `$wmiComputerSystem.GetRelated` fails with "InvalidOperation: Method invocation failed because [Deserialized.System.Management.ManagementObject#root\virtualization\v2\Msvm_ComputerSystem] does not contain a method named 'GetRelated'."