# How to disable Hibernation to be able to re-enable dynamic memory on a Hyper-V Windows 10 box?

Tags: windows-10, hyper-v, hibernate

I tried the instructions from the question below, but it did not quite work as expected. I wanted to revert but I am now unable to set the VM back to dynamic memory even though I have run powercfg -h off

[How to enable Sleep/Hibernate on a Hyper-V guest VM?](https://superuser.com/questions/1515527/how-to-enable-sleep-hibernate-on-a-hyper-v-guest-vm)

Comment: `powercfg /h off` or `powercfg.exe /hibernate off`?

Comment: for more drastic measures see https://superuser.com/questions/347927/how-to-really-turn-off-hibernation-in-windows-7